# Error while trying to setValue to an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, firebase

when I try to set my variable to an array I get this error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

The code is:

```
const [listaNotifiche,setListaNotifiche] = useState([]);
async function getNotifiche(){
    onSnapshot(collection(db, "Users",auth.currentUser.uid, "Notifiche"), async (snapNotifiche) => {
            const notifichee = [];
            snapNotifiche.forEach(doc => {
               notifichee.push(doc.data());                    
            });
            setListaNotifiche(notifichee);  
});
```

When I console log the notifichee value I get that the array has 2 elements:

```
    (2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
ActivityId: "HAZMfC5wqtbXXQulBErd"
DataInvito: it {seconds: 1641914595, nanoseconds: 364000000}
Invitato: "15nsYK6t7NbuZ0LjUIP79Lvc7zY2"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
ActivityId: "HAZMfC5wqtbXXQulBErd"
DataInvito: it {seconds: 1642158000, nanoseconds: 0}
Invitato: "15nsYK6t7NbuZ0LjUIP79Lvc7zY2"
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: I think you are not showing all the code we need to understand where the problem is. In your render, do you show `DataInvito` somewhere? If yes, could you show us how you use it?

Comment: You are trying to display your Object directly in your jsx, which won't work :)

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito yes thanks, I thought the problem was in the piece of code that I posted because the error that I was receiving was from there. Thanks again